# What is wrong with this really really simple RegEx expression?

Tags: regex

this one is really easy.

I'm trying to create a **Regular Expression** that will result in a **Successful Match** when against the following text

```
/default.aspx?
```

So i tried the following...

```
^/default.aspx$
```

and it's failing to match it.

Can someone help, please?

(i'm guessing i'm screwing up becuase of the `\` and the `?` in the input expression).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `.`(dot), which is a wildcard, 
You must escape it like `\.`.

Also, Because there is a `?` at the end of URL and `$` (end-of-input) is in the regexp, therefore, it does not match.

The correct regexp should be `^/default\.aspx(\?.*)?$`

Comment: You need to add \? before the $ or it won't match. The '?' is a reserved character too (meaning zero or 1 of the previous thing) and it should also be escaped with a backslash.

Comment: ooho. i wasn't tooo far off it. all those brackets stuff always get me stumped, also. can you explain what (?.*) does? i'm guessing the (?.*)? says that stuff in the brackets .. well, it's optional?

Comment: @Pure: actually, `(?.*)` is a syntax error.  It should have been `(\?.*)`: a question mark followed by zero or more of anything.  The question mark at the end, as you said, makes the whole group optional.

Answer (score 1):

The $ at the end of ^/default.aspx$ means 'match the end of the string', but the string you're searching ends with '?'.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this is more appropriate:

```
^/default\.aspx(\?.*)?$
```

This will match `default.aspx`, with an optional `?whatever-else-that-comes-after`.

Comment: Is there any reason to keep the $ at the end of the regex if you are doing something like ".*"?

Comment: It depends on the regex implementation because typically '.' does not match new lines.

Comment: That would explain what I've been missing. I'm usually only matching in single lines.